# Non-Interactive - Get-MgUser : Insufficient privileges to complete the operation

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I followed https://www.christianfrohn.dk/2022/04/23/connect-to-microsoft-graph-with-powershell-using-a-certificate-and-an-azure-service-principal/ to connect to Microsoft Graph but I'm getting the following error.

```
Get-MgUser -Top 1

> Get-MgUser : Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.
> At line:1 char:1
> + Get-MgUser -Top 1
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: ({ ConsistencyLe...ndProperty =  }: <>f__AnonymousType62`9) [Get-MgUser
>   _List1], RestException`1
>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : > Authorization_RequestDenied,Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Cmdlets.GetMgUser_List1
```

From what I can tell I need to consent to the permissions. I found numerous sources for how to do this for interactive sessions but nothing said how to do this for non-interactive sessions.

I tried adding -Scopes to the connection string but got this error

```
Connect-MgGraph -ClientID [snip] -TenantId [snip] -CertificateThumbprint [snip] -Scopes 'User.Read.All'

> Connect-MgGraph : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
> At line:1 char:1
> + Connect-MgGraph -ClientID 19cb80c5-b355-42bc-a892-e73d11f57ef4 -Tenan ...
> + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Connect-MgGraph], ParameterBindingException
>    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.Graph.PowerShell.Authentication.Cmdlets.ConnectMgGraph
```

How do I do this?

**EDIT**

This is how I'm connecting

```
Connect-MgGraph -ClientId $clientId -TenantId $tenantId -CertificateThumbprint $thumbPrint

Welcome To Microsoft Graph!
```

API Permissions

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your App Registration has the incorrect permissions. There are 2 types of permissions, `delegated` (aka scope), and `application` (aka role).

Reference: [Permission types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-permissions-and-consent#permission-types)

For an "interactive" session, your app will be interacting on behalf of the user, therefore uses `delegated` permissions.

For a "non-interactive" session, your app will be acting as itself, so it needs `application` type permissions.

When connecting as an application ("non-interactive"), you also don't specify the `-Scopes` parameter

Answer (score 2):

To identify the permissions needed to run a specific cmdlet of the microsoft.graph module you can use the `find-mgGraphCommand` cmdlet, e.g.:

```
(Find-MgGraphCommand -Command get-mguser).permissions
```

To identify which permissions are assigned to the current session you can use the `get-mgcontext` cmdlet, e.g.:

```
(get-mgcontext).scopes
```

If you run a interactive session you have to specify the scopes, e.g.:

```
Connect-MgGraph -Scopes user.read.all
```

To connect in the context of a service principal by using a certificate you can do:

```
#Get the certificate used as secret from the Windows certificate store
$cert = Get-ChildItem  -Path 'Cert:\LocalMachine\MY' | ?{$_.thumbprint -eq $CertificateThumbprint}

#establish connection
connect-mggraph -certificate $cert -tenantid [tenantId] -clientId [clientId]
```

btw. clientId = objectId of the service principal

Comment: I'm using a certificate. I know what permissions I need. I have the permission listed on the app in the Azure portal. Basically, I'm already doing everything you listed. But I'm still getting insufficient privileges.

Comment: sorry but that can't be - if you get : Insufficient privileges to complete the operation  
 once you run ```Get-MgUser -Top 1``` clearly indicates that the current session has not the necessary permissions. so double check by ```(get-mgcontext).scopes```

Comment: (get-mgcontext).scopes returns nothing.

Comment: ok then the problem is clear ;-) how did you establish the connection?

Comment: Updated question to make it clearer how I'm connecting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249076/discussion-between-skye-macmaster-and-toni).