# Cannot use Get-MgUser with directory.readwrite.all Graph permission

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

edit for posterity: We never figured this out, just ended up removing the app via Graph API and republishing with directory.accessasuser.all permissions.

We have an  application published on our partner tenant with directory.readwrite.all permissions granted (both delegated and application), that app has been pushed out to all of our client tenants with the same permission (and other relevant permissions). Using that app we generate access tokens via New-PartnerAccessToken, and using those access tokens we connect to client tenants via Connect-MgGraph to run Mg cmdlets on client tenants.

This method works perfectly fine with directory.accessasuser.all permissions (which is what I was originally testing on my test app with thinking our production app also had this permission), I can run every Mg cmdlet I've needed to. However when utilizing directory.readwrite.all (or any lesser permissions such as user.readwrite.all) I am getting an insufficient privileges error for every cmdlet, despite directory.readwrite.all being sufficient for a large number of cmdlets.

I'm stumped as to why, despite having an active MgGraph session with the directory.readwrite.all scope, I cannot run Get-MgUser. Below are relevant snippets of code, can anyone see what I'm doing wrong or explain why this isn't working as I expect it to? We have an active GDAP relationship with all necessary roles and the admin agents group (which I am a part of) has been added to the relationship and granted all roles.

```
$AppCredential = (New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($AppId, ($AppSecret)))

$PartnerAccessToken = New-PartnerAccessToken -serviceprincipal -ApplicationId $AppId -Credential $AppCredential -Scopes $consentscope -tenant $PartnerTenantid -UseAuthorizationCode

Connect-PartnerCenter -AccessToken $PartnerAccessToken.AccessToken

$GraphToken = ConvertTo-SecureString (New-PartnerAccessToken -ApplicationId $AppId -Credential $appcredential -RefreshToken $PartnerAccesstoken.refreshToken -Scopes 'https://graph.microsoft.com/.default' -Tenant $CustomerTenantId).AccessToken -AsPlainText -Force

Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $graphToken
```

[image: App permissions]

[image: MgContext and error]

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74209653/non-interactive-get-mguser-insufficient-privileges-to-complete-the-operation) help?

Comment: `Directory.ReadWrite.All` should allow you to query the users API. This error is quite weird. Try just in case, `Disconnect-MgGraph` and `Connect-MgGraph -AccessToken $graphToken -Scopes Directory.ReadWrite.All`

Comment: @AbrahamZinala it does not seem to, that user was having problems even establishing a session with the proper scopes, my session is open and has the appropriate permissions for the cmdlet yet I am still unable to run get-mguser.

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon You can't pair the -scopes param with -accesstoken in Connect-MgGraph, these are specified when creating the access token. In new-partneraccesstoken, https://graph.microsoft.com/.default should grant all scopes from the app I'm authenticating as, however I've tried replacing this with directory.readwrite.all and I get the same error.

Comment: Ahh myb, wasn't aware of that but it does make sense. I'm not sure why could you be getting that error really, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http#permissions from least to most privileged: User.Read.All, User.ReadWrite.All, Directory.Read.All, Directory.ReadWrite.All

Comment: No worries, thanks for the sanity check at least. I would just republish the app with directory.accessasuser.all but since directory.readwrite.all isn't working I can't even remove the app to republish it... and unfortunately a large of tenants have had DAP removed so we cannot use MSol for this purpose, I may have to look in to making Graph API calls directly if I can't get MgGraph working.